# Discord bot not working and also not showing any errors

Tags: discord.py

I have been trying to make a discord bot with python. I have tried client `on_message` events and found out about `discord.ext`. I wrote very simple code and scratched by head for 4 hrs and still can't find out the problem. The thing I know is that the code connects to the client successfully and vscode shows no problems. The bot just won't respond to anything

The code is:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='^')

@bot.command
async def test(ctx,arg):
     await ctx.send(arg)

client.run(token here)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need brackets after the decorator, use `@bot.command()` instead.